# one icon file for whole application (Vuejs, Nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

how can I create one icon file for my whole app? Currently I import into every *.vue file the icons and declare them afterwards like you can see in the following example.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-icon>
      {{mdiCheck}}
    </v-icon>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  mdiClose,
  mdiCheck
} from '@mdi/js'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        mdiClose: mdiClose,
        mdiCheck: mdiCheck
}),
</script>
```

I use Nuxt. I want to define the icons in one central file and use them in all my project without importing and declaring the icons in every single file. How can I do that?

Comment: You could probably give a read to this one: https://antfu.me/posts/icons-in-pure-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a separate component:

**components/icon.vue**

```
template>
  <div>
    <v-icon>
      {{icons[name]}}
    </v-icon>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  mdiClose,
  mdiCheck
} from '@mdi/js'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        icons: {
          mdiClose: mdiClose,
          mdiCheck: mdiCheck
        }
    }),
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    }
}
```

Than make the component global by creating a plugin

**plugins/global-components.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Icon from '../components/icon.vue'

Vue.component('icon', Icon)
```

Finally register the plugin in **nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
    ...
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/global-components.js' }
    ]
}
```

Now, you can use this component everywhere like this:

```
template>
  <div>
    <icon name="mdiCheck" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: () => ({})
}

</script>
```